# Error: Unknown method parameter type: QString&

Tags: qt, qml

On C++ side, I had this method:

```cpp
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant getFamily_byParentName(QString &parentName) const;

    // ...
}
```

I was calling the C++ method on QML:

```
onButtonClicked: {
    myClass.getFamily_byParentName(items3D.model[0]) // items3D.model[0] is a string
}
```

The above code was throwing this error at the QML line `myClass.getFamily_byParentName(items3D.model[0])`:

> Error: Unknown method parameter type: QString&

---

### Solution

The above error got resolved by declaring `QString` argument as `const`:

```cpp
Q_INVOKABLE QVariant getFamily_byParentName(const QString &parentName) const;
```

The question is: why?

Comment: omitting the `const` means you might want to be able to change the QString from where the function was called (since you get a reference to the object), however since there is a conversion from javascript to C++ this makes no sense (at least to me ;-) )

Comment: What's the *exact* type of `items3D.model[0]`? If `items3D` is const in that context it will likely be `const QString &`, i.e. exactly the type your method needs to accept. You can always add `const` to a value's type, i.e. going from `QString &` to `const QString &` is OK, but you can't take it away (otherwise what's the point, you promise in one place that you won't modify it, but can hand it off to somewhere else that does)

Comment: @Caleth `items3D.model[0]` is QML string. QML is like JavaScript, so it might be JavaScript string like `"First item"`. The scenario you suggested makes sense: QML string might be considered **un**modifiable (at least when communicating with C++), therefore when passing it to C++, I need to use `const` reference! It makes sense :)

Answer (score 4):

The QML engine converts the appropriate data types by copying the values.

In your case `QString &` is a reference to a `QString` that can not be copied, instead `const QString &` can be copied. For this reason you can not have a `QObject` as an argument since it is not copyable and instead you must use `QObject *` since a pointer is copyable.

It's the same principle as the Q_SIGNALs.

Comment: I wonder why `QString &` is not copyable but `const QString &` is copyable. Do you know any reference which can help me understand?

Comment: @user3405291 Do you understand what a reference in C++ is?

Comment: But `const QString &` is still a reference, right? I'm not sure!

Comment: @user3405291 No, it's not a reference

Comment: @user3405291 `const T &` means that the value can be copied but not modified

Comment: I'm pretty sure QML doesn't use QVariant to exchange data with c++.

Comment: @GrecKo You are correct, I had a confusion of concepts, I corrected it.

Comment: `const QString &` is a reference. It's pronounced "reference to constant QString"